# I Have a table take the table as a dataframe required answer is in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I Have a table take the table as dataframe.

```
 id | Formula | Step | Value | 
 1  | A*(B+C) |  A   |  5    |
 1  | A*(B+C) |  B   |  6    |
 1  | A*(B+C) |  C   |  7    |
 2  | A/B     |  A   |  12   |
 2  | A/B     |  B   |  6    |
```

Expected Result data frame
Solution required using spark and scala.

```
id  | Formula | Value | 
 1  | A*(B+C) |   65  | 
 2  | A/B     |   2   |
```

---

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,"A*(B+C)","A",5),(1,"A*(B+C)","B",6),(1,"A*(B+C)","C",5),(2,"A/B","A",12),(2,"A/B","B",6)).toDF("ID","Formula","Step","Value")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, Formula: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show
    +---+-------+----+-----+
    | ID|Formula|Step|Value|
    +---+-------+----+-----+
    |  1|A*(B+C)|   A|    5|
    |  1|A*(B+C)|   B|    6|
    |  1|A*(B+C)|   C|    5|
    |  2|    A/B|   A|   12|
    |  2|    A/B|   B|    6|
    +---+-------+----+-----+
```

I want the answer like this:

```
id  | Formula | Value | 
 1  | A*(B+C) |   65  | 
 2  | A/B     |   2   |
```

Comment: Please provide some more context into what you are trying to do and what have you already tried.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for us to help you, please provide some context as to what you're trying, and show us some example code to what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please give me the solution . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `Formula` and collect the `Step` & `Value` as a key value pair.

```
scala> df.groupBy($"Formula").agg(collect_list(map($"Step",$"Value")) as "map").show(false)
+-------+---------------------------------------+
|Formula|map                                    |
+-------+---------------------------------------+
|A*(B+C)|[Map(A -> 5), Map(B -> 6), Map(C -> 5)]|
|A/B    |[Map(A -> 12), Map(B -> 6)]            |
+-------+---------------------------------------+
```

Now you can write a `UDF` to substitute the variable values from `map` over `Formula` and get the results.

```
val evalUDF = udf((valueMap: Map[String, Int], formula: String) => {
...
})

val output = df.withColumn("Value", evalUDF($"map", $"Formula"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to spark with scala so, please write the complete udf.